# Unable to open websites using webView in Android, I am trying to open news websites but they are not loading

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

This is the activity which receives a url and should load a webpage in the webview.
I am getting many java script errors and as I am not able to solve them.

I have searched the api and looked at many tutorials but none seems to be solving the problem.

```
package com.tcssol.newzz.ui;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

import com.tcssol.newzz.R;
import com.tcssol.newzz.databinding.ActivityBrowseArticleBinding;

public class BrowseArticle extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ActivityBrowseArticleBinding binding;
    WebView webView;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_browse_article);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });
        binding=ActivityBrowseArticleBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        webView=binding.webView;

//        webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");

        Intent intent=getIntent();
        if(intent!=null){
            webView.getSettings().supportMultipleWindows();
            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            String url=intent.getStringExtra("Url");
            webView.loadUrl(url);
        }
    }
}

Logcat when loading the url

[INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getItem')", source: https://www.theverge.com/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-807e36bc6b59dcb1.js (2)
2024-03-14 20:34:07.778 29092-29092 chromium                com.tcssol.newzz                     I  [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getItem')", source: https://www.theverge.com/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-807e36bc6b59dcb1.js (2)
2024-03-14 20:34:09.687 29092-29092 chromium                com.tcssol.newzz                     I  [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getItem')", source: https://btloader.com/tag?o=6315858775244800&upapi=true (1)
2024-03-14 20:34:10.923 29092-29092 chromium                com.tcssol.newzz                     I  [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeItem')", source: https://theverge.coral.coralproject.net/assets/js/count.js?ts=1710428400000 (1)
2024-03-14 20:34:13.989 29092-29092 chromium                com.tcssol.newzz                     I  [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "The resource https://duet-cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/0x0:2040x1334/1080x720/filters:focal(1020x667:1021x668):format(webp)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/25310007/STK260_APPLE_CAR_CVirginia_B.jpg was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.", source: https://www.theverge.com/24085629/apple-car-dead-project-titan-ev-driverless-robotaxi (0)
2024-03-14 20:34:19.368 29092-29092 chromium                com.tcssol.newzz                     I  [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "The resource https://duet-cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/0x0:2040x1334/1080x720/filters:focal(1020x667:1021x668):format(webp)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/25310007/STK260_APPLE_CAR_CVirginia_B.jpg was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.", source: https://www.theverge.com/24085629/apple-car-dead-project-titan-ev-driverless-robotaxi (0)
```

Comment: Did you feel those errors weren't relevant to your question?

Comment: Added Logs from logcat